# HTML Vertically Center Text Next To My Logo?

Tags: html, css

I can seem to fix the heading on my blog [here](http://potion.x10host.com/blog/). I have used the following codes I have found but it doesnt seem to work.

```html
.v-center{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: can you share full code here with jsfiddle link?

Comment: Not sure what you meant. For the blog and css? Its a static page, no PHP done to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Flex box :

```html
.align-header {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: it seems to work on my end ! try to edit using inspect element to avoid cache

Comment: Oh sorry didnt realize you edited .align-header instead of .v-center. works perfectly now!

Comment: Nice to hear So, Nice this Helped you